# MYSQLI Query sum column duplicates value on rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Add all column value `'price' of all duplicate invoice numbers` on `ORDERS-TABLE with _flag = y`

I can achieve this in PHP array sorting or js but ideally, want this in the actual SQL query if possible.

Table_ORDERS

```
_id    |    _invoice_num    |    _name    |    _price    |    _flag

0          123                     bob           200          y
1          123                     bob           300          y
2          555                     mike          100          ...
3          123                     bob           300          y
3          888                     dave          200          y
```

Php:

```
<?php
 // im only after the query as its jsonen_code to ajax --

 $sql = 'select * , select(sum(price)) from table_orders Where _flag ='y' ;

 if ($results=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($results)){

            array_push($thearray,$row);

            } 
  } 

  echo json_encode(array_values($thearray));

 ?>
```

Output:

```
 /* output expecting array length 2 rows

 0 , 123 , bob , 800 , y
 1 , 888 , dave, 200 , y

 */
```

added:

```
 <?php

   $the_type = 'the_flag';

   //removes dupes 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE $the_type = '' GROUP BY _invoice";

  // need to sum the dupes now.

  ?>
```

Comment: so just get the sum of duplicate entries?

Comment: no i need the complete rows still but just adding the duplicate values together and displaying the duplicate  row once  as the OUTPUT:

Comment: shouldn't `group by` do what you need? It will still display all other records but combine duplicates.

Comment: The above is an example simplified but that not how i am implementing the actual issue.  essentially i want to display all rows but only one of a single duplicate and add all them duplicates together on its price column

Comment: group by ( removes dupes) then i want to sum the dupes but still display atleast 1 record of it then the rest as normal.. Basically every item has an invoice number so if you buy 2 phones they share the same invoice number because there on the same invoice but when i display them or search i dont want to show each row rather just show all invoice numbers and totals of cost as each row as long as the flag = 'y'

Comment: Did you try `SUM() ... GROUP BY...`?

Comment: Using sum removes all other details of the row only giving me back the correct  totals not the other columns values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(_price) AS total
FROM   _orders
WHERE  _flag = 'y'
GROUP  BY _invoice_num
```

Comment: I was missing the comma after * symbol.. This works, but i will say it adds an extra column at end of the row results with as total. This does solve my problem just not how i expected it. Thank you